Assign reference parameter for ostream to reference member variable
I'm having trouble passing a reference to std::ostream to a class constructor and assigning it to a reference member variable.
I have two files:
// ./include/HelloWorld.hpp
#ifndef __HELLOWORLD_H__
#define __HELLOWORLD_H__

#include <iostream>
#include<string>

class HelloWorld {
    public:
        HelloWorld(std::ostream& MyOut);
        void say();
    private:
        std::ostream &output;
};

#endif

// ./src/HelloWorld.cpp
#include "../include/HelloWorld.hpp"

HelloWorld::HelloWorld(std::ostream &MyOut) : output(MyOut){
    output = MyOut; // Error is thrown here
};

void HelloWorld::say(){
    this->output << "Hello World4!" << '\n';
}

When I run:
g++ -c -fPIC -Wall -Werror -o bin/HelloWorld.o src/HelloWorld.cpp

I get the following error:
src/HelloWorld.cpp: In constructor ‘HelloWorld::HelloWorld(std::ostream&)’:
src/HelloWorld.cpp:5:14: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’
    5 |     output = MyOut; // Error is thrown here
      |              ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from src/../include/HelloWorld.hpp:5,
                 from src/HelloWorld.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/ostream:405:22: note: declared here
  405 |       basic_ostream& operator=(const basic_ostream&) = delete;
      |                      ^~~~~~~~

Due to this question, I'm assuming I'm not assigning a reference to a reference. But, as far as I understand, I believe both the member variable and constructor parameter are both defined as a reference.
What am I misunderstanding here?
EDIT1: To be clear, I'm not simply asking "How do I make this work?". I'm trying to understand why when I attempt to change where a reference variable points to, there is an attempt to copy an entire object. I thought the whole point (pun intended :P) of reference variables was to avoid copying objects. I fully understand there is a reason for everything and that this does not make sense to me simply due to my ignorance. This question is intended to shore up that ignorance and learn why it works the way it does. The suggested "duplicate" question does not answer this and is 8 years old. Far to old to resurrect.

References can't be assigned to, only initialized. If you attempt to assign to a reference, it will actually assign to the object that is being referenced. And that will copy the object, and std::ostream can't be copied.

As for initialization, that's what the : output(MyOut) part is doing. You don't need to assign to output.

Dupe: Initializing an ifstream variable in constructor of class

Here:
HelloWorld::HelloWorld(std::ostream &MyOut) : output(MyOut){   // I
    output = MyOut; // Error is thrown here
};

You correctly initialize the member reference output from MyOut in the initializer list. I
You then, II,  try to assign MyOut to  output, which both are references to the same ostream. If this would compile it would do nothing, because it attempts to assign the same ostream to itself. However, std::ostream cannot be assigned or copied, that's why you get the error.
The solution is to initialize the member in the member initializer list and not assign it in the constructors body:
HelloWorld::HelloWorld(std::ostream &MyOut) : output(MyOut) {}


Ah, okay thank you.  I misunderstood what the member initializer list was doing. I thought it was simply setting a default value for the std::ostream output member. And that I still had to assign it the actual value passed in the constructor.  I understand now the member initializer list is already doing that.

But wait, It just occurred to me. Am I not allowed to change where std::ostream output points to? I know in the case of standard output, that you'll never have a second standard output to switch to. But if it were a different class, isn't the line output = MyOut; // Error is thrown here just changing the referenced location? Not the value/object referenced? I guess I don't understand why that line is trying to copy anything in the first place.

@d.lanza38 no you cannot rebind references. The have to be bound on initialization. After that all you do with the reference merely refers to the obejct that is referenced. In your code output = MyOut would assign std::cout to itself. If you want to change the stream referenced by output you can use a pointer instead.

Ah thank you @463035818_is_not_an_ai , I thought references were pointers, just a less error prone syntax for using them. I went digging for the differences between references and pointers and understand better now. This reddit post was a huge help in understanding the difference: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/18186it/i_am_absolutely_confused_on_the_topic_of/

@d.lanza38 no references are not pointers. They can be implmented as pointers under the hood. But as mental model for reference pointers are rather poor, because any conclusion you draw from that is potentially misleading and confusing. The better mental model is that a reference is the referenced object
